# Android intent getting "lost" (activity not started)

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I'm trying to add a `WebView` activity in my application, so that when opening help HTML files, they are guaranteed to be opened by a browser. 
And it works, as long as the activity is started. But functionality is fragile at best, very often the `WebViewActivity` classes `onCreate()` function never gets called, it is as if the intent sent by `startActivity` gets `lost in cyberspace`. And sometimes it works. I cannot see ANYTHING with logcat that would indicate why it would work so intermittently.

Also, I have one mobile that this works on 90% of the time, whereas another where it works 10% of the time.

Has anyone had any experienced this ?

Edit:

Code for starting activity:

```
public final void launchInternalHTMLFile(String filePath)
    {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("TheURL", filePath);
            Log.d("Tag", "launchInternalHTMLFile " + filePath);
            startActivity(intent, null);
            Log.d("Tag", "launchInternalHTMLFile startActivity called");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Tag", "launchInternalHTMLFile exception: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Code for WebViewActivity:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Tag", "WebViewActivity.onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.setContentView(mWebView);
        mWebView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("TheURL"));
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

With logcat I can see the ActivityManager receiving the intent, but when the problem occurs, I get NO entry in the log saying "WebViewActivity.onCreate"...

Oh. Forgot the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Edit: Phone on which it works most of the time is Android 4.4.2, whereas the one where it does not work most of the time is 4.4.4. Weird.

Edit: The problem has been traced to GLSurfaceView.onPause which never returns, effectively hanging the application. Although this only happens with startActivity, otherwise suspend/resume works as it should... :(

Comment: Yes, without code. The gist of the problem is there in the text. But fair enough, I'll update the question with code, but I promise it will not help pin this down.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `launchInternalHTMLFile(String filePath)` from the main thread in your activity?

Comment: It is called from the main thread of a C++ base framework (via JNI), I'm not 100% sure if these are the same. The application is based on the JUCE framework (http://www.juce.com).

Comment: I tried using runOnUiThread(...) to make sure, but it doesn't make any difference :( , thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this by delaying the starting of the embedded activity by 50 ms (using android.os.Handler.postDelayed).

Now at least, GLSurfaceView.onPause does not lock up, but still... there should be a better way to fix this.